# iOS UIImagePickerController annoying rotation (display picture) issue

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm writing app now which is using `uiimagepicturecontroller`. 
Task is very simply. U need to take a picture a thing inside place in overlay (overlay is just a circle) and then display it.
 It works fine, when user holding the iPhone vertical. Picture is cropping and displaying fine.
 Problem is **when user rotate their iPhone horizontal**. I suppose camera is rotating and i can't display photo as i'd like.

Any ideas **how to remove autorotatin**?

1. Device orientations in my `target->general` is only `Portrait`
2. I tried override autorotate method in `UIImagePickerController` and it didn't works

Any idea how to fix it? Or any tricky tricky method to display image correctly?

Best regards, 
David.

EDIT: Solution for this is use AVCam and write "own" class to take a picture.

Comment: if the image you get is rotated, then rotate that image by (-90) and then display it. to know whether the image is rotated or not, i think checking the width/height ratio would help.

Comment: @santhu That's not the correct answer too. Even i will rotate image it won't be in the right place.

Comment: well you have left us no choice .Post the entire code on how you handling the picker,image,crop, may be u might have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

i think it works:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)pickerinput didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [pickerinput dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    UIImage *image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    UIImageView *yourImgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initwithimage:image];
    //please add this
     yourImgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't works as expected. Picture is still rotating.

Comment: can you add this:
yourImgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
_img = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:_image scale:_imgScale orientation:_imgOrient];
_imgOrient = _img.imageOrientation;
_imgScale = _img.scale;
```